# Set maximum volume in Ubuntu/Gnome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I have the following issue with my volume settings (Ubuntu 12.04, 3.2.0-49-generic, Gnome 3, Lenovo X220): When I set the volume to maximum using the hardware volume keys, I get to "100%" in the Audio settings. However, there is quite some range beyond the 100% which I want to use to get decent sound. The latter range is only available via the audio settings menu:

[image]

Using the hardware keys, I can only go down but not up in the range beyond the "100%" setting. Is there a way of making the full range accessible to the volume keys? I checked alsamixer, which shows that the volume is at its maximum.